# Division Alternating Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

In order to solve a Physics question, I was able to get to the point where I figured out that the answer was the sum of the following series:

$$x = 42 + 14 + 2.8 + (14/15) + (14/75) + ...$$

As you can see, $$42/14 = 3, 14/2.8 = 5, 2.8/(14/15) = 3, (14/15)/(14/75) = 5$$, etc.

How can I represent this, and, how can I solve this for $x$?

I'm a high school student who has covered sequences and series of a high school level, but even with that knowledge wasn't able to solve such a question. Thanks in advance, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you sum the geometric series $\frac 13+\frac 19 + \frac {1}{27}+...$?

Comment: Split it into two parts, one series of the terms with even index, the other for the terms with odd index, $42, 2.8, \frac{14}{75},\dotsc$ and $14,\frac{14}{15}, \frac{14}{225},\dotsc$.

Answer (score 1):

$$x=14\left(\overbrace{3+1}+\overbrace{\frac15+\frac1{15}}+\overbrace{\frac1{75}+\cdots}\cdots\right)\\
=14\left[(3+1)\left(1+\frac 1{15}+\frac1{15^2}+\cdots\right)\right]\\
=14\cdot 4\cdot \frac 1{1-\frac1{15}}=?$$